# How to get the second highest to lowest value record on the based on order by field in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, jsonb

Here I have a JSON field I want to select the second highest to lowest record on every id the
data is

JSON looks like this

```
{
    "user": [
        {
            "user_name": "Devang",
            "user_weight": 0.7676846955248864
        },
        {
            "user_name": "Meet",
            "user_weight": 1.1021
        },
        {
            "user_name": "Devang",
            "user_weight": 0.16163873153859706
        },
        {
            "user_name": "Rajan",
            "user_weight": 0.22163873153859706
        }
    ],
    "address": [
        {
            "address_name": "India"
        }
    ]
}
```

The query I have executed is

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT id, ('{user,'||index-1||'}')::text[] as json_path, value->'user_weight'
FROM user_table, jsonb_array_elements(json_field->'user')
WITH ordinality arr(value, index) WHERE arr.value->>'user_name' IN ('Devang', 'Meet') order by id, value->'user_weight' DESC
) select * from cte;
```

getting this kind of record

```
id  json_path   ?column?
1   {user,1}    1.1021
1   {user,0}    0.7676846955248864
1   {user,2}    0.16163873153859706
2   {user,0}    0.7676846955248864
2   {user,1}    0.07447325861051013
```

I want the second highest to lowest records like this

```
id  json_path   ?column?
1   {user,1}    1.1021 # this is the highest one in 1 id so I do not need this
1   {user,0}    0.7676846955248864
1   {user,2}    0.16163873153859706
2   {user,0}    0.7676846955248864   # this is the highest one in 2 ids so. I do not want
2   {user,1}    0.07447325861051013
```

output would be

```
id  json_path   ?column?
1   {user,0}    0.7676846955248864
1   {user,2}    0.16163873153859706
2   {user,1}    0.07447325861051013
```

Glance at here [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=199a56b135ce96164cd9b1095b645e72)

Any answer will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, but if you feel like playing with window functions you could `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` the weights by id and eliminate the first ranks in an outer query:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, ('{user,'||index-1||'}')::text[] as json_path, (value->'user_weight')::text::numeric AS weight
  FROM user_table, jsonb_array_elements(json_field->'user')
  WITH ordinality arr(value, index) 
  WHERE arr.value->>'user_name' IN ('Devang', 'Meet') 
  ORDER BY id, value->'user_weight' DESC
) 
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT cte.*, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id,weight DESC
                 RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS r
  FROM cte) j
WHERE r > 1;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e808a905f21388abcb34942a2d140fb4)

Answer (score 1):

Using the window function and partition we can grab and eliminate the first row like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT id, ('{user,'||index-1||'}')::text[] as json_path, value->'user_weight', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id order by value->'user_weight' DESC ) as row_num
   FROM user_table, jsonb_array_elements(json_field->'user')
    WITH ordinality arr(value, index) WHERE arr.value->>'user_name' IN ('Devang', 'Meet') order by id, value->'user_weight' DESC
) 
select * from cte where row_num>1;
```

Here [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ab50c5ebdf46224147eb1793f28fbafe)

Comment: Nice. Keep in mind that this query will fail if multiple records share the same max(weight). So, it will skip just one record and show the other(s). cheers and happy coding